# Recovering RAID5 - using Linux "mdadm"

Tags: raid, data-recovery

Using Linux `mdadm` to recover from failed disk `/` partition.
Here  are titles of the steps I took so far - I can post detailed copy if it helps.
( I am not sure how to post file link here...)

The last response to "run" is :

```
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ sudo mdadm --run /dev/md0
mdadm: failed to start array /dev/md/0: Input/output error
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$
```

**What would be my next step to "activate" the array ?**

```
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ cat /proc/mdstat  1
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ cat /proc/mdstat  2
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0    3
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ sudo mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0    3
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0  4
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ sudo mdadm --run /dev/md0recovering
```

Comment: Have you checked the status of the members of the array? What is the output of `dmesg` after the `mdadm --run` command? It could be that two of your devices are broken, which means all your data can be lost.

Comment: Please read last comment -  on run. Here it is again nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ sudo mdadm --run /dev/md0 
mdadm: failed to start array /dev/md/0: Input/output error
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$

Comment: Here is a part of dmesg [ 3193.003771] md/raid:md0: not clean -- starting background reconstruction
[ 3193.003843] md/raid:md0: device sdb17 operational as raid disk 1
[ 3193.003849] md/raid:md0: device sdb4 operational as raid disk 0
[ 3193.006900] md/raid:md0: cannot start dirty degraded array.
[ 3193.007721] md/raid:md0: failed to run raid set.
[ 3193.007733] md: pers->run() failed ...
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ sudo mdadm --run /dev/md0 
mdadm: failed to start array /dev/md/0: Input/output erro

Comment: it saiz "starting background reconstruction" what does that mean ?

Comment: How many devices are supposed to be in your RAID array? I see only two in your dmesg output (`sdb17`, and `sdb4` .. both of which seem to be on the same physical device - which is probably a Very Bad Idea). If your array consisted of three devices - it should start up in a degraded (at risk) state. If it consisted of more than three - then it won't be able to start up until the missing devices are made available again. Review `/proc/partitions` (or `lsblk`, or `blkid`) to find out which devices are currently "visible"

Comment: Please edit the original question and add additional information there with proper formatting. The information is very hard to read when it is in comments.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't the next step be to mount it?

I think I've used this guide before, maybe it will help you out?

https://kb.synology.com/en-uk/DSM/tutorial/How_can_I_recover_data_from_my_DiskStation_using_a_PC

You should definitely consider whether any disk has failed because trying to recover with a faulty drive still in place may be worse than removing it. I'd at least try to check out the SMART status of each disk. The read-only nature of the setup in the article means if you get it wrong it won't damage your array, you can just start over with more or different disks.

Comment: I have installed lvm2 and run  sudo cat /proc/mdstat lvs getting this nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ sudo cat /proc/mdstat lvs 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
26 : inactive sde24[0](S) sde25[1](S)
      204666880 blocks super 1.2
       
md0 : inactive sdb17[1] sdb4[4]
      409335808 blocks super 1.2
       

      
unused devices: <none>
cat: lvs: No such file or directory
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$  I had to delete some mdx output to fit here

Comment: Using lvs give no output   nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ sudo lvs
[sudo] password for nov25-1: 
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$